# How to make negative lookahead work with end of line text

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex like the following:

```
.{0,1000}(?!(xa7|para(graf))$)
```

using Java.
I was expecting that it would cause the following text to fail:

blaparagraf

because paragraf is found at the end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `.{0,1000}` will match the entire subject, hence it's not followed by `xa7` or `paragraf` (it's followed by `$` only).

You want negative lookbehind:

```
.{0,1000}(?<!xa7|paragraf)$
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, as a curiosity would it be possible to change it to use negative lookahead?

Comment: @bryan-rasmussen I initially tried to come up with something with negative lookahead, with no success.

Answer (score 9):

It is a common a mistake to misplace assertions. If you want to use lookahead, the pattern is something like this:

```
^(?!.*paragraph$).*$
```

This matches ([as seen on rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/7Q3t8QEieA)):

```
something something para
paragraph something something
```

But doesn't match:

```
something paragraph
```

So the key difference here is that we start looking ahead at the *beginning* of the string, before we match `.*` (or `.{0,1000}` in your case). Of course, what we're looking for isn't simply `paragraph$`, but rather `.*paragraph$`.

That said, to check that a string doesn't end with something of finite length, lookbehind when supported is the most natural solution.

```
^.*$(?<!paragraph)
```

Comment: So ^(?!.*paragraph$).*$ at first checks if the string does NOT end with paragraph and second if the whole string matches .*?